# Asp.NET Core: cross-origin request to services (preflight) returns code 204 instead of 200

Tags: asp.net-core, cors

I have Asp.NET Core Web API application and trying to implement authorization but came across with CORS problem - my dev services and ui host on different ports of localhost.

On login page I get token and redirects to next page. At this time data requests to services start. But server responses with status 204: No Content for preflight request...
Although, preflight response returns Access-Control-Allow-Origin: * ...

The Startup.cs looks like:

```
public void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)
{
    // ...
    services.AddCors(options =>
    {
        options.AddPolicy("Policy",
            builder => builder.AllowAnyOrigin()
            .AllowAnyMethod()
            .AllowAnyHeader() );
    });
    services.AddAuthorization();
    services.AddMvc() // ...


public void Configure(IApplicationBuilder app, IHostingEnvironment env, ILoggerFactory loggerFactory)
{
    app.UseCors("Policy");
    app.UseMvc();
}
```

Do I miss something on server side? (on client side angular's interceptor just adds Authorization header with token)

P.S. I use VS Code on OSX for developing (although it's not important as I guess)

UPDATE:

as @tpeczek adviced, I've change cors configuration to:

```
        options.AddPolicy("Policy",
            builder => builder.WithOrigins("http://localhost:80", "http://localhost")
            .AllowAnyMethod()
            .AllowAnyHeader()
            .AllowCredentials() );
```

but can't get rid of error

[image: Preflight looks like this]

UPDATE 2:

The error I get is

```
XMLHttpRequest cannot load localhost:5000/api/<method-name>;. No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource. Origin 'localhost'; is therefore not allowed access. The response had HTTP status code 500.
```

But once I remove `[Authorize]` attribute from controller it works fine. So the problem is in token checking?

UPDATE 3:
The problem was in accidentally removed functionality :- ( Works now

Comment: `204 NO CONTENT` does your controller/Middleware return any data?

Comment: @JoelHarkes middleware returns "await context.Response.WriteAsync(JsonConvert.SerializeObject(response, new JsonSerializerSettings { Formatting = Formatting.Indented }));" when getting token. When going to data, middleware doesn't return anything. Controller isn't reached. The only middleware I'm using I get from https://stormpath.com/blog/token-authentication-asp-net-core

Comment: If this still doesn't work please include the preflight request headers in your question.

Comment: attached screenshot to post's body

Comment: What error exactly are you trying to get rid of? As @tpeczek noted, the `204 NO CONTENT` status code is not an error. Instead for an `OPTIONS` request, a response with no content/body but just headers is exactly what’s expected

Comment: Most likely the Chrome is complaining about one of the headers not being allowed. The dev tools console should contain detailed error.

Comment: @sideshowbarker, the error in dev tools is "XMLHttpRequest cannot load http://localhost:5000/api/<method-name>. No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource. Origin 'http://localhost' is therefore not allowed access. The response had HTTP status code 500."

Comment: @user1820686 From your last comment it doesn't seem that the issue is with CORS any longer, you have moved pass the preflight request and now something else is erroring in your app.

Comment: Please update your question to include that error message. That 500 indicates a problem on the server side that has nothing to do with CORS. The message is just saying there is no  Access-Control-Allow-Origin on the 500 error page you’re receiving. Which is not necessarily a problem because you won’t run into it if you figure out what is causing the 500 error on the server side and fix it

Comment: @user1820686 Regarding your last update, in my opionion initially you had an issue with CORS (due to that `Authorization` header in request) and now there is different issue probably in the area you are suspecting, which deserves separate investigation.

Comment: @tpeczek, definitely you were right. During my vain attempts to fix, I removed necessary functionality by mistake. Found out that by git diff:( Anyway, thank you all for your help!

Answer (score 23, accepted):

The `204 NO CONTENT` status code is perfectly valid for CORS preflight response (see [here](https://www.w3.org/TR/cors/#cross-origin-request-with-preflight-0)).

Your problem results from fact that you request contains `Authorization` header which makes it a "credentialed request". In such case you can't use wildcard for `Access-Control-Allow-Origin` and you must specify `Access-Control-Allow-Credentials` (you can read more [here](https://www.w3.org/TR/cors/#security))

```
services.AddCors(options =>
{
    options.AddPolicy("Policy", builder => builder
        .WithOrigins("<Origin One>", "<Origin Two>", ...)
        .AllowAnyMethod()
        .AllowAnyHeader()
        .AllowCredentials()
    );
});
```

Comment: I've just added builder.WithOrigins("http://localhost:80", "http://localhost"), preflight returns following headers: Access-Control-Allow-Credentials:true Access-Control-Allow-Headers:authorization and Access-Control-Allow-Origin:http://localhost but got the same error on main request

Comment: @user1820686 The correct format of origin is `<scheme> "://" <host> [ ":" <port> ]`. The easiest way to get them right is putting the same thing that comes in `Origin` header of request.

Comment: It was until November, apparently. I just lost half a day to this: all the browsers have now updated and it must be a "200". :(